# Mod_Rewrite and REQUEST_URI funnelling

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use a *Front Controller* design pattern for my website, so I want to point everything to, let's say, `index.php`.

Inside `index.php` I want to split the `REQUEST_URI` up into different things and decide what to do next from there.

How can I write my `.htaccess` to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress does this exactly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thank you! i knew it was a quick answer but I couldnt find it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Apache version 2.2.17 or greater, I'd suggest [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource). I've found it to be slightly faster in these cases, i.e. Frontend Controller.

Comment: Interesting, Thank you, I hadn't heard of that one.